# Prettier extension is not working after March 2021 update (version 1.55)

Tags: prettier, prettier-vscode

I set my default formatter to Prettier and the extension is not working after the update. I restarted and even reinstalled vscode and it still won't work. Please advise?

Answer (score 0):

Check your document fully for errors/bugs. You may have missed an element. Sounds simple but check that you have  wrapped around correctly.

Go down line by line and check elements and attributes carefully.

Prettier will only correct a recognisable html doc and will not, well, make it pretty.